# musl libc: path to linux headers

Tags: linux, libc, musl

I am trying to build lfs and using musl libc implementation instead of glibc. Glibc actually allows to set the path to linux kernel headers (--with-headers, like that), but musl don't.

Moreover musl readme says following

> The system used to build musl does not need to be Linux-based, nor do
>   the Linux kernel headers need to be available.

How is this even possible? libc should know what capabilities presents in the kernel and this information is usually provided by headers.
Any suggestions?

ps: I am running fedora 21

Comment: It uses [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Some may fail.